# Routine Check Between Two Dates Perl

Tags: perl, date

Trying to build a routine script in perl that will twice a month on the (15th and the End Of The Month)

Run a query that gets all users that were created within a date interval. (on the 15th get all customers created from the first till that day! and at the end of the month get all users created from 15th to that current day)

Normally Id say this wouldnt be an issue to just do it within the query. However this script will be run twice a month every month! I have to take into consideration shorter months and leap years!

Is there anyway to do this within perl without going into an overly large if condition?

Comment: what database ?  what type is the created column?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Date::Calc module function Days_in_Month

```
  use Date::Calc qw(:all);

#  Days_in_Month
      my ($year,$month) = (2013,12);
      $days = Days_in_Month($year,$month);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why tackle this in perl?

cron is perfectly able to run files scripts at checkpoints.

you can then use the date interval from the query, as you would normally.

Comment: I could very well be wrong, but it seems to me the question isn't about how to run it twice a month, but rather how to come up with the date constraints once it is running.

Comment: If that is the case, then cron isn't going to help :)